# What are those rings on overhead powerlines called?

Tags: power, high-voltage

[image]

[image]
The only things I'm finding is something called a corona ring.

**My questions are**

1. What are they called?
2. Why are they always in layers of rings?

Comment: Read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_ring  what a Corona ring really is. Note the comment under the 2nd photo: *Corona rings on insulator strings* Your photos show the **insulators**, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulator_(electricity)

Comment: The many rings make the **creepage distance** longer, it makes it more difficult for the high voltage to find a path to the other (grounded) side of the insulator.

Comment: I see what you mean in the bottom picture, but there are no rings in the top picture.

Comment: I guess OP confused the isolator's dishes (rings) for Corona rings.

Comment: Yeah I meant dishes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are insulators.

Their shape is designed to maximize the length electricity would have to creep over their surface from cable to mast, and to provide dry and clean "gaps" even in bad weather.

A corona ring is something different (wikipedia has an article).

Comment: They are in layers because one is not enough and one insulator that length would break easily.